# How to update a ObservableCollection with data coming to fast from multithread events?

Tags: c#, multithreading, event-driven

I'm working on a binding library for an Aar. This Aar sends List of data, on a new thread thanks to RX java.

These datas (which are tags scanned with a rfid device) are sent through events to my program which suscribe to

```
public delegate void InventoryStreamTagsHandler(IList<string> epcS);

/// <summary> observable à s'abonner </summary>
public interface IInventoryCallBack
{
    /// <summary> réception d un stream </summary>
    event InventoryStreamTagsHandler StreamResult;
}
```

with

```
private void OnStreamResult(IList<string> epcS)
```

Its purpose is to display a

```
ObservableCollection<StreamResult> StreamResultS
```

with

```
public class StreamResult : MtcTools.DispatchNotifier
{
    public string Epc { get; }

    public DateTime LastUpdate { get; private set; } = DateTime.Now;

    public int Count { get; private set; } = 1; 

    public StreamResult(string epc)
    {
        Epc = epc;
    }

    public void IncrementeCountAndDate()
    {
        Count++;
        OnPropertyChanged("Count");

        LastUpdate = DateTime.Now;
        OnPropertyChanged("LastUpdate");
    }
}
```

On each data received, I search for an Epc already known and call IncrementeCountAndDate if it exist otherwhise I create a new StreamResult that I add to my ObservableCollection

But the datas are coming to fast and in multithread that i don't have time to process them
It's a xamarin form application

Comment: You are getting a `List<string>` or a `string` on an event?

Comment: Im' getting a List<string>

Answer (score 1):

Add the data to a queue which get processed by another thread?

If the bottleneck is just on the UI, you could add code to your *IncrementeCountAndDate* method to only call *OnPropertyChanged* if the time since the last update is greater than, for example, 250 milliseconds.

Comment: Actually right now , I'm using a queue OnGuiUpdate with private void  OnStreamResult(IList<string> epcS)
        {
            foreach (var epc in epcS)
            {
                _epcS.Enqueue(epc);
            }
        }  and then In a thread calling OnGuiUpdate (function with loop) which dequeue and update the observable collection. I was wondering if there was a prettier way to do it

Comment: You need as @manulateigne said  a thread-safe `Queue` where on one end  ( on your event you add items to it ) and then you could just run a separate thread that keeps popping items off the queue and dissipates them to `Task`-s.